# Clearing Cell Values of a table if matching criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to sort through a specific range of cells and look to see if the LEN(gth) of that cell is equal to 20.  If it is, I would like to clear the contents of said cell and move to the next until they are all evaluated.

I have this report that is pulled from a website and exported to excel and the annoyance is a 0.0% that shows up as pound signs (# x's 20).  I've tried other macros that search for strings, it completely ignores 0%, the one constant is that each cell that this appears in is exactly 20 characters in length.

What should happen is that I am:

```
1  Searching C3:U20 
2  for cell.len = 20 
3  if activecell = matches criteria 
4  then clear.contents
5  Goto 1 until all activecells with a len of 20 are cleared
```

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

G

****EDIT****
Since I couldn't make that work, I used a "work around".  It's inefficient as all *blarp* but since it's only used on a small table it doesn't really matter.  I just have to do this in "three" seperate scripts.  I found that if I converted the ranges from Percentage formatting to General, I could just look for the overflow number as a string.  Then once they are "cleared" I just reconvert those columns to a percentage formatting:

```
Sub sub_ConvertToGeneral()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''  Convert the Percentage Columns to General Format
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Columns("F:F").Select
    'Application.FormulaBarHeight = 2
    Range("F:F,H:H,L:M,O:O,S:S,U:U").Select
    Range("U1").Activate
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    'Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    Range("A1:B1").Select
End Sub

Sub sub_Overflow()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''  Find Overflow and delete every instance of it
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim FindString As String
    Dim rng As Range
    FindString = "2.6965E+308"
50
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Main Import").Range("C1:U20")
            Set rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto rng, True
                ActiveCell.ClearContents
                Do
                Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
                GoTo 50
                Loop While Not rng Is Nothing
                Else
            End If
        End With
    End If
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Sub sub_ConvertToPercentage()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''  Convert the General Columns to Percentage
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Columns("F:F").Select
    'Application.FormulaBarHeight = 2
    Range("F:F,H:H,L:L,O:O,S:S,U:U").Select
    Range("U1").Activate
    'Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    Range("A1:B1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cells to be cleared actually contain exactly 20 characters (So LEN(A1) would display 20), then Select the cells you want to examine and try:

```
Sub dural()
    For Each r In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If Len(r.Text) = 20 Then
        r.Clear
    End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

```
This version will clear cells with a value greater than 1.0E+307:

Sub dural()
    For Each r In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If IsNumeric(r.Value) Then
            If r.Value > 1E+307 Then
                r.Clear
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, I thought this would work, but apparently not, the script fires without a hitch on a cell that is 20 characters in length, but what I just figured out is the real issue behind the pund signs is a stack overflow.  The cells are formatted in a way that gives me a 0% when the cell is selected, but the actual value is 2.69653970229347E+308.

I just want to clear those out lol...

Comment: How about we clear cells whose value exceeds 1.E+308 ??

Comment: This would be fine by me, except I am unsure how to do that.  I am getting better, but I still have issue with loops and searches and stuff like that.  I've been working on this for about a week trying to modify other code to suit my needs, I finally broke down to ask here.

Comment: Couldn't get that to work, gives me a Type Mismatch error on the If statement

Comment: Probably means your **selection** included non-numerical cells.  My latest version avoids this.

Comment: I am finding the biggest problem it seems is that no matter which type of looped search that I perform, whether .Value is added or not, is going off the "face" display of the cell.  I can search for 10 #'s (##########) and it finds it, but if the column is too wide or too narrow (allowing or disallowing # symbols), then it won't catch it.  Searching for 1E+307 isn't catching either :/

Comment: Even if I convert the cell to text or general and search for 2.69653970229347E+308 it won't work, it has to be the truncated version (2.70E+308) in order to catch it.  Even my work around above doesn't work 100% of the time, but it catches some (most) leaving me with very little clean up.

Comment: **Please update this post with your final solution to this interesting problem**

Comment: I have, it's listed above below the *EDIT* line.  The solution wasn't very eloquent, but it was still effective.